# how to set position of <div> tag

Tags: html

I have set the position of  tag using following line

```
<div id="myTestDiv" style="border: 2px solid rgb(100, 149, 237); color:#23238e; background-color:white; position:absolute; top:458px; left:605px; width:210px; height:162px; display:none" >
```

the problem with this is, its working fine in my machine, but when i deploy the code on some other machine, the position and style (background color) are not displayed properly...

do any one have any idea, how to set uniform style and position of div for all resolution

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably say what browser and version you want this to work on. You have `display:none` which will make the element not display -- i.e. it is not supposed to show up. I would recommend specifying the border color in hex (#XXYYZZ) instead of decimal rgb() notation for maximum browser compatibility. Otherwise it looks fine to me.

Comment: What browser are you using on the other platform. If the browser supports the CSS version you are using they should all support them. Check on one of the CSS reference sites to check the support of different CSS attributes on different browsers. If the colours are also affected, it could be an issue with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I can't see why it doesn't work the same way on all machines.

1. Since you are hard coding the numbers for top and left, where you see it on the monitor(position) depends on the size of the monitor. On your's it might appear exactly at the center but on a bigger/smaller screen, it won't. It just appears exactly at 458px from top and 605px from left. Try using % values.
2. The color difference may be due to the hardware ie. the condition ans settings of the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with percent values.
Avoid rgb(xxx, xxx, xxx) syntax.
And always check yout html from old to modern browsers.

Comment: why do you ask to avoid rgb()?

Comment: hey guys i have tried everything, now i have used % for top and left but still its not displaying uniformly for all browsers across all machines